# keyFilter remove special characters

Tags: primefaces

I am working with Primefaces `inputMask` and `keyFilter`

```html
<p:inputMask  inputStyleClass="#{(newDesWeb eq '_')? 'selectfile' : 'form-control lg200 input-sm'}  errorCible"
                    id="zoneResidenceAssure" styleClass="#{(newDesWeb eq '_')? 'ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched' : ''}  errorCible"
                    style="width: 100%"
                    value="#{devisPresBean.currentAssureDevisBean.adresseActuelle.zipCode}" maxlength="#{msg['form.control.input.codepostal.maxlength']}">
                    
                    <c:ajax onevent="displayAjaxSatus" event="change" execute="@this" render="@this" />
                    <p:keyFilter  regEx="[0-9]" for="zoneResidenceAssure" />
                </p:inputMask>
```

How to remove speciale characters like "_" and "-" also '

Comment: When i use `<p:keyFilter regEx="/[\d]/"/>` it only allows numbers and "_" and "-" are not accepted?

Comment: This is not JSF specific. This can be done by using this regex `[^-_']` - this will basically allow every character except the specified behind `^`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that well documented, but the `p:keyFilter` expects a [JavaScript regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), as all the [examples in the documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/keyfilter?id=getting-started-with-keyfilter) start with `/`. So you need to use `/[0-9]/` instead of `[0-9]`.